# Creality Ender 3 - printing in front of the build plate

Tags: calibration, build-plate

I am trying to print my first test but my Creality Ender 3 starts printing near the front edge and within 10 seconds is printing in front of the tray (off onto my table).  I really think it should be starting the print in the middle and then never going so close to the edge and even over it

What can I do?

Comment: Have you found & fixed the problem? If any of the answers helped you to get an answer to your question or come to your own conclusions then please do vote & accept an answer (using the tick button next to it). This helps us reduce the [unanswered questions list](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/unanswered) & stops the question from being bumped once in a while. If you found another answer (than those already posted), please add that answer (& accept after 48 hours) to share your experience with the community. If you have not been able to address the problem please update your question.

Answer (score 4):

When a print is not printing on the build platform, you either:

1. Have the incorrect settings in the slicer (e.g. Ultimaker Cura, [a common mistake is that the "origin at center" option is active](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/6450/5740)), or
2. Have the center of the bed incorrectly stored in your firmware. (See: [How to center my prints on the build platform? (Re-calibrate homing offset)](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6375/how-to-center-my-prints-on-the-build-platform) or [Recalibrating Home-position](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/recalibrating-home-position)).

Note that the most simple change (after you verified the slicer settings and confirmed that it still does not print in the center) is adjusting the settings in the slicer (bed settings, of start G-code script), this way you do not need to compile and upload new firmware (e.g. if you are uncomfortable or inexperienced in doing so), but, fixing it in the firmware is the best solution. Why? If you change the offset in the slicer you force the bed dimensions to a new position that *you know* where it is, while if changed in the firmware, the printer "*knows*" the actual size and the limits.

---

*To fully answer your question, we need a little more information what slicer you use and what the current settings are. From your question it sounds as if the offset is more than a few millimeters. Usually this hints to an incorrect slicer setting (frequently Ultimaker Cura).*

Answer (score 2):

The Ender 3 has its standard homing position not set to a point on the build plate but rather at the physical position of the endstops. That is a couple millimeter in front and at the side of the *front left* corner. To make it clear, *home* or *(0,0,0)* is *not* the center of the build plate but some millimeters off the *front-left corner*.

To move the home position away from the physical switch positions and onto the build plate's front left corner - should you want to - you will need to switch the firmware of your printer.

A walkthrough I had with an Ender3 (the same machine type) is at [Recalibrating Home Position](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/6660/8884)